# Cannot start Oracle NoSQL Database on localhost

Tags: oracle-nosql

Trying to install Oracle NoSQL 18.1.27 on Mac

Setup:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

$ echo $KVROOT
/Users/sn/Software/oraclenosql/kvroot

$ echo $KVHOME
/Users/sn/Software/oraclenosql/kv-18.1.27
```

Used this command to install:

```
java -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar makebootconfig -root $KVROOT -port 5000 -host localhost -storagedir $KVHOME/kvdata/ -harange 5010,5030 -storagedirsize "1 gb" -store-security none
```

Test using jps:

```
$ jps -m
8866 Jps -m
8826 kvstore.jar start -root /Users/sn/Software/oraclenosql/kvroot
8831 ManagedService -root /Users/sn/Software/oraclenosql/kvroot -class Admin -service BootstrapAdmin.5000 -config config.xml
```

Trying to start the db

```
$ java -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar ping -host localhost -port 5000
Could not connect to registry at localhost:5000 Unable to connect to the storage node agent at host localhost, port 5000, which may not be running; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Can't find store topology: Could not contact any RepNode at: [localhost:5000]
```

And when trying to ping:

```
SNA at hostname: localhost, registry port: 5000 is not registered.
    No further information is available
Can't find store topology: Could not contact any RepNode at: [localhost:5000]
```

Logs show these:
adminboot.log

```
2020-03-26 20:05:07.344 UTC INFO [BootstrapAdmin] Starting in bootstrap mode
2020-03-26 20:05:07.348 UTC INFO [BootstrapAdmin] Starting commandService on rmi://localhost:5000/commandService
2020-03-26 20:05:07.448 UTC INFO [BootstrapAdmin] Successfully created a secure proxy for commandService
2020-03-26 20:05:07.531 UTC INFO [BootstrapAdmin] Starting admin:CLIENT_ADMIN on rmi://localhost:5000/admin:CLIENT_ADMIN
2020-03-26 20:05:07.640 UTC INFO [BootstrapAdmin] Successfully created a secure proxy for admin:CLIENT_ADMIN
2020-03-26 20:05:07.713 UTC INFO [BootstrapAdmin] Started AdminService
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting the NOSQL you are trying to ping. If you want to start :

1. $ jps -m ( this will not shows any service if its not started )
2. $ nohup java -jar $KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar start -root $KVROOT&
3. Press enter again to come out of the nohup
4. $ now run jps -m again it will shows the process running status

Note: if its properly configured then there is no issue, else it will throw errors. Kindly follow Proper document and google the error :)

Thanks,